# If a resistance of $0$ ohms and $x$ ohms are in parallel does all current pass through the $0$ resistance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

If a resistance of $0 \Omega$ and $x$ (and $x>0$) are in parallel does all current pass through the $0$ resistance?

> For instance in the following circuit:
>
> [image]
>
> Set variable resistor to o ohms:

**I know that current takes the path of least resistance but surely some would still go through the $12$ ohm resistor?**

I am asking why no current goes through the higher resistance. If the lower resistance was 1 (from the variable resistor) the current would go through the higher resistor, so why when the lower resistance is 0 does all the current go through it.

Comment: With $R_3=0 \;\Omega$, total resistance including $R_1$ would be $6+0 =6\;\Omega$

Comment: Think of what voltage you'll see across the 2 parallel resistors, and from that work out the current through R2.

Answer (score 7):

$14 V, R=(6+0)\Omega=6\Omega$, thus $I=V/R= 14/6 A$. This current will flow through the battery and $R_1$ (and through the ZERO $\Omega$ resistor $R_3$).
No current will flow through $R_2$. The potential difference over 
$R_2 = 0$.